# Getting and error "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found" in oomp installer

Tags: eclipse, oomph

Trying to setup eclipse development environment using [oomph](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/may/article3.php) but getting an error **"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found"**

See stack trace:

```
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=10053 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
at org.eclipse.oomph.targlets.internal.core.TargletContainer.forceUpdate(TargletContainer.java:778)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.targlets.impl.TargletTaskImpl$4.run(TargletTaskImpl.java:1128)
at org.eclipse.oomph.util.pde.TargetPlatformUtil.runWithTargetPlatformService(TargetPlatformUtil.java:119)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.targlets.impl.TargletTaskImpl.perform(TargletTaskImpl.java:1036)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3021)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2964)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4160)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4154)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.access$0(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4152)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2955)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2930)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:2861)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:555)
at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:681)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Software being installed: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1467382214442
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Missing requirement: Infocenter_feature Feature 1.0.0 (org.eclipse.help.infocenter_feature.feature.group 1.0.0) requires 'org.apache.commons.el 0.0.0' but it could not be found
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=1 Cannot satisfy dependency:
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 From: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1467382214442
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 To: org.eclipse.help.infocenter_feature.feature.group 0.0.0

Took 2610 seconds.
There are failed tasks.
Press Back to choose different settings or Cancel to abort.
```

Any clues or pointer to resolve this and successfully setup eclipse dev environment using oomph?

Comment: Not nearly enough information is provided to know what might be going on. What version of the installer? What OS? What package did you select to install? etc.

Comment: Latest version of installer on eclipse.org. OS: Ubuntu 14.04. I have selected all components under **Eclipse platform for commiters** Check here https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1078951&goto=1736761&#msg_1736761

Answer (score 0):

From the log, you are trying to install `org.eclipse.help.infocenter_feature.feature.group` and this feature requires `org.apache.commons.el`.

Can you tell what you have selected in the installer?

Is this a setup task you have written?
If so you probably need a P2 Setup Task containing a P2 Repo providing this bundle.

---

EDIT:

To reproduce your problem:

Step 1: select any Eclipse "Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Commiter" is one possibility:

[image: Oomph product selection]

Step 2: select the setup of the project "UA" (UA means [user assistance](https://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Assistance)) under "Platform":

[image: Oomph project selection]

The setup script of this project has a problem. For the moment the "UA" project can not be setup with Oomph, until [Bug 497350](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497350) is solved.